# Integer solutions $d = \frac{ab}{a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}}$

Tags: diophantine-equations

$$d = \frac{ab}{a + b + 2\sqrt{ab}} = \frac{ab}{(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2}$$

What are the positive integer solutions?

The majority of solutions are when $a=b$, so that $a = 4d$.

Comment: An idea: $a$ and $b$ must be perfect squares. $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$ as well.

Comment: @SalmonKiller No they don't, only $ab$ must be square

Answer (score 0):

$$b=m^2a$$
$$d=\frac{m^2a^2}{(1+m)^2a}=\frac{m^2a}{(1+m)^2}$$
$$a=(1+m)^2k,\quad b=m^2(1+m)^2k,\quad d=m^2k$$
For example,

$$m=1\rightarrow (a,b)=(4k,4k)$$
$$m=2\rightarrow (a,b)=(9k,36k)$$
$$m=3\rightarrow (a,b)=(16k,144k)$$
$$...$$

Comment: Is $m$ always an integer?

Comment: @Element118, yeah I realized it can be a rational number.